# MySQL Shell cant add instance due to 'unconnected' user

Tags: mysql, replication

I am having an issue adding an instance to my ReplicationSet with MySQL 8.0.28 and MySQL Shell

```
rs.addInstance('a.b.c.d:3306')
```

the response I get is

```
Adding instance to the replicaset...

* Performing validation checks

This instance reports its own address as a.b.c.d:3306
a.b.c.d:3306: Instance configuration is suitable.

* Checking async replication topology...

* Checking transaction state of the instance...

WARNING: A GTID set check of the MySQL instance at 'a.b.c.d:3306' determined that it contains transactions that do not originate from the replicaset, which must be discarded before it can join the replicaset.

a.b.c.d:3306 has the following errant GTIDs that do not exist in the replicaset:
2b575744-e07d-11ec-ada9-00ff6b3adad4:1-67

WARNING: Discarding these extra GTID events can either be done manually or by completely overwriting the state of a.b.c.d:3306 with a physical snapshot from an existing replicaset member. To use this method by default, set the 'recoveryMethod' option to 'clone'.

Having extra GTID events is not expected, and it is recommended to investigate this further and ensure that the data can be removed prior to choosing the clone recovery method.

Please select a recovery method [C]lone/[A]bort (default Abort): C
* Updating topology
Waiting for clone process of the new member to complete. Press ^C to abort the operation.
* Waiting for clone to finish...
NOTE: a.b.c.d:3306 is being cloned from x.y.z.x:3306
ERROR: The clone process has failed: Clone Donor Error: 1184 : Aborted connection 554 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'mysql_innodb_rs_10' host: 'xxx' (init_connect command failed). (3862)
ERROR: Error adding instance to replicaset: Clone Donor Error: 1184 : Aborted connection 554 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'mysql_innodb_rs_10' host: xxx' (init_connect command failed).
Reverting topology changes...

Changes successfully reverted.
ERROR: a.b.c.d:3306 could not be added to the replicaset
ReplicaSet.addInstance: Clone Donor Error: 1184 : Aborted connection 554 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'mysql_innodb_rs_10' host: 'xxx' (init_connect command failed). (RuntimeError)
```

I can't find any information on how to proceed with this, any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your user has all of the required permissions, then the first thing to check based on (init_connect command failed) in your description would be the init_connect variable on both master and slave:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'init_connect';
```

It should be the same on both servers.
(The 'unconnected' in your subject will simply be referring to the db - which is not an issue).